# Execute environment in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have Java Maven project in my Eclipse IDE. I found strange selection of execute environment:

[image]

I'm building application for Java ver. 1.8. For this reason I have downloaded JDK1.8. What does J2SE-1.5 means there?

Comment: J2SE-1.5 means compatibility mode (this case with Java 1.5). See https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/8-compatibility-guide-2156366.html

Answer (score 0):

This generates Java **code that can be executed with a Java 5 VM** as long as you are using nothing from the JRE system library that was introduced after Java 5 (e. g. [`String#isEmpty()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#isEmpty--) which requires Java 6 or higher).

To this problem points out the warning, which you will get:

> The compiler compliance specified is 1.5 but a JRE 1.8 is used

For this problem, there is the compiler flag `--release` (*Project > Properties: Java Compiler*) which requires at least a Java 9 JRE/JDK and [Eclipse Photon (4.8)](https://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.8/jdt.php) and the selected execution environment must be at least JavaSE-1.6 and not higher than the highest available JRE/JDK (*Window > Preferences: Java > Installed JREs*). Which means in your case you can also install a newer JDK than the Java 8 JDK to write Java 8 code as long as you do not want to use something that has been removed from the JRE system library in the meantime.